# Knockout.js - Ideas on transforming JSON data to HTML

Tags: html, json, knockout.js

I have an observableArray `self.CustomerOrders` which I populate with

```
self.CustomerOrders.push(new CustomerOrder(self.getOrderId(), today.toLocaleDateString() , self.selectedCustomer2(), JSON.stringify(self.cart(),null,4)));
```

where

- `self.getOrderId()` is a method to get an Id for the order,
- `today.toLocaleDateString()` prints today's date,
- `self.selectedCustomer2` is the selected customer of the order and
- `self.cart` is another observableArray which includes all ordered items.

Here is how I populate `self.cart`

```
self.cart.push(new orderedItem(product.id, product.name, product.price, product.quantity()));
```

and here is my foreach

```
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: CustomerOrders">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: date"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: customer"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: details"></td>
                <td data-bind="click: $parent.selectedOrder"><a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#display-order">View</a>
                </td>
                <td data-bind="click: $parent.selectedOrder"><a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-order">Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td data-bind="click: $parent.selectedOrder"><a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-order">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I succeed in saving all those data to the `CustomersOrders` observable array and then I print them in my UI using `foreach`. My problem is that the `self.cart` items are printed as JSON and I do not want to display JSON to the user but HTML.

How to implement this ? 
Any ideas ?

Comment: What does your `CustomerOrder` function look like? You have a `JSON.stringify` in there that is coverting your `self.cart` object into a string. Is that what you intended? Are you `JSON.parse`ing it back at some point?

Comment: Also, show your HTML bindings.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. I just want a way to print the JSON object to HTML. No need for downvote if you didn't understood my requirements. Thank you.

Comment: That's because your requirements are unclear.

Comment: I don't think so but anyway. I was very clear but people like to downvote as I can see.

Comment: Of course you think you've been clear. You see your code, you have been working on it for a while now. None of us has, though. Don't take the downvote so hard. I'll remove mine once your question is clearer. The data model is still missing - as I said, try to build a jsFiddle.

Comment: @AthanasiosEmmanouilidis: People are downvoting because your question *isn't* clear. Your edit is a step in the right direction, but is `details` where `cart` ends up? It isn't clear still. You should show your view model (the `CustomerOrders`) as well as what `cart` looks like. This should actually be really simple if you give us enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so don't `JSON.stringify` your `cart`. Then, assuming your `Details` binding is where the `cart` part is supposed to end up, and it's supposed to be an array, you can just nest `foreach` bindings like this:

```
<td>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: details">
        <li data-bind="text: someProperty"></li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

where `someProperty` is whatever property of the cart you want to display.

Of course, you can choose whatever html elements suit your requirements.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't knew I can nest foreach.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that the self.cart items are printed as JSON

Well, that's not surprising.

```
self.CustomerOrders.push(
    new CustomerOrder(
        self.getOrderId(), 
        today.toLocaleDateString(), 
        self.selectedCustomer2(), 
        JSON.stringify(self.cart(),null,4)   /* guess what that does */
    )   
);
```

Just do

```
self.CustomerOrders.push(
    new CustomerOrder(
        self.getOrderId(), 
        today.toLocaleDateString(), 
        self.selectedCustomer2(), 
        self.cart
    )
);
```

and use regular knockout bindings in your view to display the `cart`.

Comment: Does not work this way. self.cart does not get printed by foreach. JSON.stringify works as expected.

Comment: @AthanasiosEmmanouilidis: What do you mean by "works as expected"? You haven't explained why you are using `JSON.stringify` in the first place. It coverts your object to a string, why do you want to do that? If you then want to access the properties of the original object, you will need to `JSON.parse` again.

Comment: I was simply using it because only this method seemed to make the contents of my object to be printed by foreach.

Comment: Yes, and you are completely wrong with that approach. Stop "banging on it until it works somehow". Have you actually tried my suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I have tried and it doesn't works. And I don't use that approach. If I don't use JSON.stringify I will get [Object Object] printed with the foreach. Anyway, as I said in my answer, I probably have found the answer to my question. Thank you all.

Comment: You have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I just told you the truth. Your answer prints [Object Object] in the foreach. How can I transform that ?

Comment: @AthanasiosEmmanouilidis: It prints `[Object object]` because it's an object. That's the standard `toString` for a javascript object. You need to put both what your `cart` object looks like and what your html bindings look like in your question and *then* somebody will be able to help you. Until then, you haven't given anybody enough information to help you. You are stuck on what you *think* the solution is (`JSON.stringify`) but you are completely barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Without seeing your view model and HTML bindings it's impossible to say. If you set up a minimal jsFiddle that shows the problem, I might be able to point out where your mistake is.